# How do I edit the contents of HTML5 template tag with jQuery before cloning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I am currently trying to set up a template that I can fill out in a for loop and clone each time. This is what I have so far which works fine for cloning the templates HTML but I am stuck trying to manipulate my template before cloning it.

Trying to do something like a `find()` on a clone does not work, I think it has something to do with the template being a `#document-fragment`?

Could somebody give me an example with jQuery on how to do this? Maybe something as simple as manipulating the `h1` title before cloning the template?

```
<div class="template-holder"></div>

<template class="my-custom-template">
  <div class="example">
    <h1>Example</h1>  
    <h2>Example 2</h2>
    <div class="customDiv">Testing</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
var template = $('.my-custom-template');

var clone = template.clone();

$('.template-holder').append(clone.html());
```

JSFiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lmyyyb4k/2/

**Edit:**

It looks like jQuery itself does not have any support for document fragments: http://james.padolsey.com/stuff/jQueryBookThing/#doc-fragments

So I guess I will have to combine some vanilla JS with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a different element than template, it works:

```
<div class="template-holder"></div>

<div class="my-custom-template" style="display:none">
  <div class="example">
    <h1>Example</h1>  
    <h2>Example 2</h2>
    <div class="customDiv">Testing</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This would manipulate the h1 title in the template before cloning the template:

```
var template = $('.my-custom-template');
template.find("h1").text("Changed H1 Title!");

var clone = template.clone();
$('.template-holder').append(clone);
clone.show();
```

Comment: A template tag would be ideal though since it already suppresses everything inside the template tag as default behavior(audio, video, display, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to answer, but the best solution I've found is to build the content of your template as a string, and use `.replaceWith('<template>'+html+'</template')` to just replace the tag outright.